# OpenEmu gba .sav file to VBA possible?

Tags: emulation

I started a save file for pokemon Delta Emerald v1.1.4, using the OpenEmu emulator. I tried running the .sav file on VBA (VisualBoyAdvance), and it says it loaded, but opening the game only shows "new game" and "options", and not my original save.

How do I transfer a .sav file for Gameboy Advance from OpenEmu to VBA?

Here's the .sav file if you need it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LfVRB5rRUZrACHyrvk-7ZhNObiq_dWI9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You'd need to convert from the format used for platform A to that used for platform B. Unless that's just a simple "magic value" (first 1+ bytes, usually) then it's going to be hard and need programming. Worth checking out [this online tool](https://savefileconverter.com/#/mister) and the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/euan-forrester/save-file-converter) for more info. No idea if it's capable, just a random search result that seemed relevant.